# Acces data from another class with a method and store that data in an variable

Tags: java

For a project i am making an program where I have 3 classes: House, room, temperature. Every house have one or more rooms (array list of objects) and every room has an temperature (object) in it. Temperature has 2 variables: max temperature (double) and actualTemperature (double). I need to make an method that counts when the actualTemperature is higher than the max temperature.

So I have this method in HOUSE class:

```
int getHighTempratures(){
   return ....;
}
```

After all i need to print out something like this in the main:
"In your house is in (1) of the 2 rooms the temperature higher than the maximum temperature"

(1) : need to get this with the method above

I've already tried to store the actualTemprature in a local variabele in the House class using a Getter. and later print this variable in the main.

The getter doesn't work at al. im new to this so its a little difficult. I hope somebody can help me.

The temperature class:

```
public class Temperature {
 private double ActualTemperature;
 private double MaxTemperature;

public Temperature(double ActualTemperature, double MaxTemperature)              
    this.ActualTemperature = ActualTemperature;
    this.MaxTemperature = MaxTemperature;
}

public double ActualTemperature() {
    return ActualTemperature;
}

public double maxTemperature() {
    return maxTemperature;
}
```

---

The room class:

```
 public class Room {
  private String roomName;
  private Temperature temperature;

public Room(String roomName, Temperature temperature) {
    this.roomName = roomName;
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

public String getroomName() {
    return roomName;
}

public Temperature getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}
```

---

The house class (where I need the method):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class House {
 private String street;
 private int  number;
 private ArrayList<Room> rooms;
 private int HighTempratures;



public House(String Street, int number) {
    this.street = street;
    this.number = number;
    rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
}


public void addRoom(Room rooms) {
    rooms.add(rooms);
}


public int getHighTempratures() {
    return HighTempratures;
}
```

created this objects:

```
House house1 = new House (" St. street", 21);

Temperature temperature1 = new Temperature(20.0, 19.0);
Temperature temperature2 = new Temperature(22.7, 24.01;

Room room1 = new Room("Donovan", temperature1);
Room room2 = new Room("Jayden", temperature2);

house1.addRoom(room1);
house1.addRoom(room2);
```

so: with the method in the house class I need to print something like this: in **1 of the 2 rooms its hotter than the maximum.**

Comment: (1) Decide what to call your class `House` or `Home` and be consistent. (2) Explain how exactly you used your getters and why this approach "*did not work*"

Comment: It makes sense to add `IsRoomTooHot()` method to your `Room` class.

Comment: Sorry, see it now. gonna change it to house.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need number of rooms that are too hot, it can be done like this:

```
public int getHighTempratures() {
    int numberOfHighTemperatures = 0;
    for (Room currentRoom: rooms) {
        if(currentRoom.getTemperature().maxTemperature() < currentRoom.getTemperature().ActualTemperature() ){
            numberOfHighTemperatures++;
        }
    }

    /*

    You can use this instead to make your code look better, but then you need to make method in Room class

    for (Room currentRoom: rooms) {
        if(currentRoom.isTooHot()){
            numberOfHighTemperatures++;
        }
    }

    */
    return numberOfHighTemperatures;
}

/*
//code to put into Room class to use prettier code
public boolean isTooHot(){
    if(temperature.maxTemperature() < temperature.ActualTemperature()){
        return true;
    }
    return false
}
*/
```

So in conclusion you need to check every room separately if it's too hot.

Answer (score 0):

Per PM 77-1's comment, adding an `IsTooHot()` method to your `Room` class would be a simple solution.

Add the following method to `Room`:

```
// return boolean indicating if room temp is above max temp
public boolean isTooHot() {
    return temperature.ActualTemperature() > temperature.maxTemperature();
}
```

And `House.getHighTemperatures()` becomes:

```
int getHighTemperatures() {
  int count = 0;
  for (Room room : rooms) {
    // increment count if room is too hot
    if (room.isTooHot()) count++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: That is a better way to do it. thanks for your help. I appreciate it!